# Javascript reduce with condition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce

How can I use reduce in order to return the sum only if the accumulator (a) and the currentValue (b) is both an Integer?

My guestGroups Array:

```js
     "guestGroups":[  
         {  
            "bookingNumber":"21.05.201827.05.20181208",
            "arrivalDate":"2018-05-19T22:00:00.000Z",
            "departureDate":"2018-05-25T22:00:00.000Z",
            "customerId":1,
            "fields":[  
               {  
                  "value":"2",
                  "display_name":"Personen Anzahl",
                  "servicio_tags":[  
                     "person-number-info"
                  ]
               }
            ],
            "number":"041"
         }
      ]
```

```js
  getPersonNumberAdult() {
    const personNumberField = this.fields.find(f => {
      return f.servicio_tags && f.servicio_tags.includes('person-number-info');
    });
    return personNumberField ? Number(personNumberField.value.match(/\d+/)[0]) : '-';
}
```

```js
isInt(value) {
  let x = parseFloat(value);
  return !isNaN(value) && (x | 0) === x;
}
```

```js
guestInfo: t.guestGroups
    .map(gg => gg.getPersonNumberAdult())
    .reduce((function(a, b) {
        if (a && b) {
            {
                if (this.isInt(a) && this.isInt(b)) {
                    return a + b
                } else {
                    return '-'
                }
            }
        }
    }), 0)
```

This gives me `undefined`.

Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Please share your `guestGroups` object.

Comment: Where is `getPersonNumberChild` defined?

Comment: Maybe because its `NumberAdult` not `NumberChild` ?

Comment: Need to return `a` not a new string in the `else`

Comment: When it's not an integer, just return `a`. Otherwise you'll end up with `NaN` after trying to add `-` to a number.

Comment: This code snippet gives me the desired result `guestInfo: t.guestGroups.map(gg=> gg.getPersonNumberAdult()).reduce((function(a, b) { {if (isNaN(b)) {return '-'} else {return a + b}}}), 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getPersonNumberAdult` should not return either a number or a string. It should return an integer or `NaN` if no number is available. The `'-'` should only be used in formatting the output in the end.

Once you got that, you can either filter out invalid values and sum the rest:

```
const sum = t.guestGroups
.map(gg => gg.getPersonNumberAdult())
.filter(v => isInt(v)) // or just !isNaN
.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

or just sum them and then replace `NaN` by `'-'` if any value was invalid:

```
const sum = t.guestGroups
.map(gg => gg.getPersonNumberAdult())
.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
const output = isInt(sum) ? String(sum) : '-';
```

depending on which behaviour you want.

Comment: What do you mean by "*if both values are not an integer*" - `'-'` is never an integer?

Comment: This code snippet gives me the desired result @Bergi `guestInfo: t.guestGroups.map(gg=> gg.getPersonNumberAdult()).reduce((function(a, b) {
{if (isNaN(b)) {return '-'} else {return a + b}}}), 0)`

Comment: @AntonHörl For that behaviour I'd recommend the second snippet